# Why should GetHashCode implement the same logic as Equals?

Tags: c#, equality, gethashcode

In [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) page it says:

> Warning:
>
> If you override the GetHashCode method, you should also override Equals, and vice versa. If your overridden Equals method returns true when two objects are tested for equality, **your overridden GetHashCode method must return the same value for the two objects**.

I have also seen many similar recommendations and I can understand that when overriding the Equals method I would also want to override the GetHashCode.  As far as I can work out though, the GetHashCode is used with hash table look-ups, which is not the same as equality checking.

Here is an example to help explain what I want to ask:

```
public class Temperature /* Immutable */
{
    public Temperature(double value, TemperatureUnit unit) { ... }

    private double Value { get; set; }
    private TemperatureUnit Unit { get; set; }

    private double GetValue(TemperatureUnit unit)
    {
        /* return value converted into the specified unit */
    }

    ...

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Temperature other = obj as Temperature;
        if (other == null) { return false; }
        return (Value == other.GetValue(Unit));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Value.GetHashCode() + Unit.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

In this example, two Temperature objects are considered equal, even if they are not storing the same things internally (e.g. 295.15 K == 22 Celsius).  At the moment the GetHashCode method will return different values for each.  These two temperatures objects are equal but they are also not the same, so is it not correct that they have different hash codes?

Comment: If you are never going to store your `Temperature` object in a `HashSet` or a `Dictionary`, then you *could* get away with ignoring `GetHashCode`, but you *really, really shouldn't*. It would be horrible practice.

Comment: @MattBurland I would add to the list also LINQ `Distinct`, `GroupBy`, `ToLookup`, `Union`, `Intersect` etc.

Comment: @IvanStoev: Absolutely, which really illustrates why you shouldn't. You may be confident that you didn't put something into a `HashSet`, but, especially with something like LINQ, you can't be sure that the internal implementation of one of those is using the HashCode (and almost certainly it is).

Comment: Just to clarify I am trying to implement both.

Comment: @Ben, so then what's the question. Warning message: "...If your overridden **Equals** method returns **true** when two objects are tested for equality, your overridden **GetHashCode** method must return the **same value** for the two objects".

Comment: Are you asking **how** to implement `GetHashCode` in your case?

Comment: @IvanStoev read the last line of my post: These two temperatures objects are equal but they are also not the same, so is it not correct that they have different hash codes?

Comment: @Ben: You really need to distinguish between what it means to be equal in the context of the physical world of temperature measurements and what it means to be equal in the world of your C# code. If your `Equals` method returns true, then the two object *must* return the same hash code. If they don't, your code will break in many interestingly frustrating ways...

Comment: I have nothing to add to @MattBurland's comment, thank you Mat!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When storing a value in a hash table, such as `Dictionary<>`, the framework will first call `GetHashCode()` and check if there's already a *bucket* in the hash table for that hash code.  If there is, it will call `.Equals()` to see if the new value is indeed *equal* to the existing value.  If not (meaning the two objects are different, but result in the same hash code), you have what's known as a collision.  In this case, the items in this bucket are stored as a linked list and retrieving a certain value becomes O(n).

If you implemented `GetHashCode()` but did *not* implement `Equals()`, the framework would resort to using *reference equality* to check for equality which would result in every *instance* creating a collision.

If you implemented `Equals()` but did *not* implement `GetHashCode()`, you might run into a situation where you had two objects that were equal, but resulted in different hash codes meaning they'd maintain their own separate values in your hash table.  This would potentially confuse anyone using your class.

As far as what objects are *considered* equal, that's up to you.  If I create a hash table based on temperature, should I be able to refer to the same item using either its Celsius or Fahrenheit value?  If so, they need to result in the same hash value *and* `Equals()` needs to return true.

**Update:**

Let's step back and take a look at the purpose of a hash code in the first place.  Within this context, a hash code is used as a quick way to identify if two objects are *most likely equal*.  If we have two objects that have different hash codes, we know for a fact they are *not* equal.  If we have two objects that have the *same* hash code, we know they are most likely equal.  I say most likely because an *int* can only be used to represent a few billion possible values, and strings can of course contain the complete works of Charles Dickens, or any number of possible values.  Much in the .NET framework is based on these truths, and developers that use your code will assume things work in a way that is consistent with the rest of the framework.

If you were to have two instances that have different hash codes, but have an implementation of `Equals()` that returns true, you're breaking this convention.  A developer that compares two objects might then use one of of those objects to refer to a key in a hash table and *expect* to get an existing value out.  If all of a sudden the hash code is different, this code might result in a runtime exception instead.  Or perhaps return a reference to a completely different object.

Whether 295.15k and 22C are equal within the domain of your program is your choice (In my opinion, they are not).  However, whatever you decide, objects that are equal *must* return the same has code.

Comment: If you don't override equals it will default to reference equality.

Comment: Moreover, when the framework _looks_ in the dictionary, it'll use the hash code first, so you could store `295.15K` in the dictionary, but when you look for `22C`, it won't be found. Is this what you want? Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: yes this is what I would expect, 295.15K is not the same as 22C so it should be stored in a different bucket right?

Comment: @Ben: If that's the case, then it's your equals implementation that is wrong. You should compare value *and* unit. If you need to be able to compare if two temperatures are the same regardless of unit, then you should probably have a separate method *just for that*

Comment: If it were me, I wouldn't do *unit conversion* implicitly like that.  A *Temperature* class should have a *Unit* property, and instances that different in which unit they're measured in should *not* be considered equal.  Now, you could have a `.ToCelsius()` and `.ToKelvin()` method, and *that* would return an instance that is equal.

Comment: @MattBurland surely you wouldn't suggest that 295.15K is not equal to 22C?  They are equal!  They are also not the same because they are constructed using different units and so should be put in different hash table buckets.  I appreciate all of your attempts to explain this to me (thanks) but so far I don't see why having a different hash code is a problem.

Comment: @Ben: They are not equal because they have different units. You can't have two things be equal but have them hash to different buckets. That is a horrible idea. Either hash them to the same bucket, or have them not be equal if the units are different. Or provide an alternative method to compare equals without regard to units. The easiest fix for you existing code is to just convert your value to one particular unit (say `K`) and then hash that value as your hash code. Now 295.15k and 22C will hash the same, and be equal as well.

Comment: @MattBurland thanks mat, can you please explain why it is a "horrible idea"?  I think this is the real point of this question that I want to ask.

Comment: @Ben: as has been explained already in the comments (and in the documentation you quoted) because *that is the convention*. The convention is what *all other code* is going to be working on. The example of putting values in a dictionary for example, the internal .NET library code is assuming that *values that are equal have the same hash code* and the *values that have different hash codes are not equal*. Now, maybe you don't use `Dictionary` *at the moment*, but if you ever use it, or HashSet, or LINQ, your code *will break*. And it will likely break in really hard to trace ways.

Comment: Agreed.  Anyone who uses your class *expects* objects that are equal can be used to refer to the same key in a hash table.  Every other class works this way.  If you break this rule, you can potentially create some really weird, *really* hard to track down bugs in the future.  The same hash code suggests objects are *probably* equal, Equals tells you if they are *definitely* equal.  Those two concepts need to go hand in hand.

Comment: Thanks for the Update Mike, it has helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> **Warning**:
>
> If you override the GetHashCode method, you should also override Equals, and vice versa. If your overridden Equals method returns true when two objects are tested for equality, your overridden GetHashCode method must return the same value for the two objects.

This is a *convention* in the .NET libraries. It's not enforced at compile time, or even at run-time, but code in the .NET library (and likely any other external library) expects this statement to *always* be true:

> If two object return `true` from `Equals` they will return the *same hash code*

And:

> If two objects return *different hash codes* they are **NOT** equal

If you don't follow that convention, then your code will break. And worse it will probably break in ways that are really hard to trace (like putting two identical objects in a dictionary, or getting a different object from a dictionary than the one you expected).

So, *follow the convention*, or you will cause yourself a lot of grief.

In you particular class, you need to decide, either `Equals` returns false when the units are different, or `GetHashCode` returns the *same hash code* regardless of unit. You can't have it both ways.

So you either do this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    Temperature other = obj as Temperature;
    if (other == null) { return false; }
    return (Value == other.Value && Unit == other.Unit);
}
```

Or you do this:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    // note that the value returned from ConvertToSomeBaseUnit
    // should probably be cached as a private member 
    // especially if your class is supposed to immutable
    return Value.ConvertToSomeBaseUnit().GetHashCode();
}
```

Note that nothing is stopping you from also implementing:

```
public bool TemperaturesAreEqual(Temperature other)
{
    if (other == null) { return false; }
    return (Value == other.GetValue(Unit));
}
```

And using that when you want to know if two temperatures represent the same *physical* temperature regardless of units.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Matt, I think I always knew I was going to have to follow the convention, but when the convention seems to be hard to understand, then it makes me want to find out more about why the convention is the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

Two objects that are equal should return the same HashCode (two objects that are different could return the same hashcode too, but that's a collision).

In your case, neither your equals nor your hashcode implementations are a good one. Problem being that the "real value" of the object is dependant on a parameter: there's no single property that defines the value of the object. You only store the initial unit to do equality compare.

So, why don't you settle on an internal definition of what's the `Value` of your `Temperature`?

I'd implement it like:

```
public class Temperature
{
    public Temperature(double value, TemperatureUnit unit) { 
       Value = ConvertValue(value, unit, TemperatureUnit.Celsius);
    }

    private double Value { get; set; }

    private double ConvertValue(double value, TemperatureUnit originalUnit,  TemperatureUnit targetUnit)
    {
       /* return value from originalUnit converted to targetUnit */
    }
    private double GetValue(TemperatureUnit unit)
    {
       return ConvertValue(value, TemperatureUnit.Celsius, unit);
    }    
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Temperature other = obj as Temperature;
        if (other == null) { return false; }
        return (Value == other.Value);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Value.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

That way, your internal `Value` is what defines if two objects are the same, and is always expressed in the same unit.

You don't really care what `Unit` the object has: it makes no sense, since for getting the value back, you'll always pass a value. It only makes sense to pass it for the initial conversion.

Comment: Nope, they won't be equal. The value is converted in the constructor. The stored "value" will be celsius

Comment: Value is private in OPs example, who cares how you internally store it?